# ¿Sería semánticamente correcto insertar una etiqueta a dentro de una etiqueta nav?

Tags: html, html5

Estoy construyendo un sitio en Internet y me gustaría cumplir con la semántica en todo lo posible, pero aquí sigo teniendo ciertas dudas. Pues eso, he navegado por la web y la **gran mayoría** son así (tanto ordered como unordered):

```
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Mi pregunta es **si semánticamente esto sería correcto y por qué**:

```
<nav>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</nav>
```

Desde mi punto de vista, se ve más limpio y sencillo con etiquetas `a` en vez de listas, tanto ordenadas como desordenadas.

La especificación del Consorcio W3C [dice](https://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-nav-element):

> The `nav` element represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.

Lo que me da más a mi favor, puesto que los elementos `a` son utilizados para enlazar a otras páginas o a la misma. Si el elemento `nav` especifica que su contenido tiene enlaces a otras páginas, ¿por qué no utilizar solamente el elemento `a`?

**Todo esto, teniendo en cuenta que lo que busco es una "lista" desordenada de enlaces**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es correcto usar solo las etiquetas `a`.

Lo que tu estas proponiendo, es una lista desordenada de enlaces. Es más recomendado (y más correcto semánticamente) usar una lista desordenada de items.

Por otro lado hay dos buenas razones para usar listas en tu página web:

1. El uso de listas puede ayudar a dar una idea de la estructura de su sitio, que es buena en términos de `SEO`, pero también si las personas usan `CSS` personalizados o lectores de pantalla por razones de accesibilidad.
2. Bastante útil cuando se trata de crear hojas de estilo (relacionado con lo anterior). No necesitas crear tu propia forma de anidar los elementos.Si usas listas, puedes acceder  desde allí. Luego, puede concentrarse en obtener la hoja de estilo correcta y proporcionar diferentes estilos para diferentes niveles de jerarquía, primero, último, impar o incluso elementos de la lista.